# ERROR: query has no destination for result data

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

I ve created function and trigger as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION New_Ticket()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$$BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM Ticket WHERE productID=(SELECT MAX(ticketID) FROM Ticket);
    RETURN NEW;
END$$ 
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;

CREATE TRIGGER New_TicketTr
AFTER INSERT ON Ticket
FOR EACH ROW execute procedure New_Ticket();
```

After I do insertion as follows:

```
INSERT INTO Ticket (ticketID, Problem, Status, Priority,LoggedTime,CustomerID,ProductID) VALUES 
(1, 'Cannot play games.', 'open', 1,'2005-05-13 07:15:31.123456789',1,1);
```

I get ERROR message:ERROR:  query has no destination for result data
HINT:  If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function "new_ticket" line 2 at SQL statement.
Can anyone help me? What is the problem there?

Comment: As your trigger does not do any processing, you could just remove it. The question is: why would you need a trigger in the first place, What problem are your trying to solve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are not doing anything with that query. Neither a DML nor returning the result into a variable or record.

Comment: Can I make some variable like in PHP and assign the query to it and return the variable?  If not what would u suggest?

Comment: As far as I know, you can't. Triggers are for executing DML for very special situations... perhaps if you explain what you are trying to achieve, we can give you some alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

You misinterpret the **basic concept of a trigger**. A trigger function can manipulate the row it has been called for. Or it can execute additional DML statements to manipulate other data in the database.

But there is no way to "return a variable", because there is no calling instance it could return values to.

Now, if you define *in your question* what you intend to do with the row you query, we might be able to help.

However, the query itself does not seem to make any sense. Why would a `productid` match`max(ticketid)` in table `ticket`?

Also, you are creating a trigger `AFTER INSERT`. It is nonsensiccal to `RETURN NEW` in the trigger function in such a case.

You really need to get a grasp on the whole concept first.
Start by reading the [chapter **Triggers** in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/triggers.html).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I wanted to display all the rows which have been inserted after Insertion. AND yes, sorry there was a mistake, it should be SELECT * FROM Ticket WHERE productID=(SELECT MAX(productID) FROM Ticket);